# Rename app in google play store

Tags: android, publish

I published my app in google play store and tried to find it. But I found it by project name. My project name wasn't like app name.

But many people installed my app. How can I change the name without uploading a new app?

Project name is: quarrynew

App name is: quarry

I changed my project name and uploaded it. But it wasn't changed. I'm waiting a few days.

People can find my application by typing "quarrynew". But never find it by typing "quarry".

Application name is "quarry". Only project name and filename was "quarrynew".

```
<string name="app_name">Quarry</string>
```

Comment: I cant fin an app by either name. Can you post a link?

Comment: Whate is the package name ?

Comment: You can change anything about the application except the packagename and the keystore used to sign it.

Answer (score 66):

The project name will not be used in Google Play Store. 
And the "app_name" is generally used for your title bar or as title in the android launcher,desktop,..

The display name of your App in Google Play Store is defined in the application settings in https://play.google.com/apps/publish/ changes may take some time(hours,days).

[image]

[image]

Comment: So you can rename an app without doing any changes to it?

Comment: Yes, the name in the play store will change. But the name of the actually installed app stays.

Comment: Hi @Bold Bat if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: This is outdated as of 2022.

Answer (score 59):

You can rename your app in Google Play console **New UI August 2020** by this way

Store presence -> Main store listing -> App Name

[image]

Comment: After changing the "App name" do I have to republish the app or changes will be directly applied to the Play Store page of the app?

Comment: Just press Save button and changes will be directly applied to the Play Store page

Answer (score 57):

**AppName**:- app name showing after installing apk in your device.

If you want to change playstore name follow below steps.

**According to new playstore design**

**Step 1** : Open Developer Account https://play.google.com/apps/publish/

**Step 2**: Select the app that you want to change your playstore app name. After select app, this dialogue is shown.

[image: deshboard]

**Step 3**: Then scroll down a little bit you can see option **Store Listing**  Click on it. in your right side, you can see title field That is the name you can see in the playstore.  See screenshot below

[image]

Change the title and submit an update. And it's done.

**Note: after submit it will take 24 hours to update your info in playstore (in 24 hours)**

Comment: Can you use different titles for different languages ? Is this a good idea ? For example my app in english is "Quartets Card game" but I would like to name it "Quartett Kartenspiel" in German. At the same time, I have a generic (original) name, "Match4App" with the website "match4app.com".

Comment: Yes, you can use different names for different languages. You can also put different images and different videos for different languages.

Comment: 1. Go to : https://play.google.com/apps/publish; 2. Select account; 3. Select Store listing; 4. Select the app; 5. Update Title.

Comment: This is outdated as of 2022.

Comment: can someone please provide an update as of 2023?

Answer (score 5):

App can be easily renamed in StoreListing, unable to showcase image due to rep points.

Initially we had issues when we were trying to rename our app from Punch to AhaPunch but after 15days we were able to do so successfully.

Comment: Could you please add more details about the solution you provide?

Comment: if you could share , what all we can rename , whenever trying to reply , always be elaborative that helps others

Answer (score 3):

It is quite easy to be done.
Just follow these steps and you will be able to do in seconds.

1. Open Google Play Console and select the App you want to change.
2. Go to Store Listing and in Title Field enter the **NEW NAME** .
3. Submit at the bottom of the page.

After 24 you will be able to see the new name on the play store.

Answer (score 2):

In 2023 You need to go "Grow" section right under the "Release" section. There is "Store presence" then "Main store listing". There you can change or update your app name, short description, full description, and graphics.

Answer (score 0):

You should rename your app(s) on the Play Store, where you have uploaded it.

Answer (score 0):

Google reads the appName from your gradle file (not from Manifest or string files). You must change the appName: File/Project Structute/Variables:android - appName.