# how can I customize the word with which my app can be found in the playstore?

Tags: google-play-services

I have uploaded my application to the playstore. My application has 3 letters called "xxx" (I can not put the name), and although it is published I can not find it when writing its name. It's been 3 days since I did it. Where can I customize the word or words I would like for users to find it?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the app's name (Launcher App Label) by renaming the [`android:label`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#label) inside application node:

```
android:label="@string/app-name"
```

or based from [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14069703/rename-app-in-google-play-store):

> 1. Open your [developer account](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/).
> 2. Select your app that you want to change the name.
> 3. Find the **Store Listing** in the dropdown and click it.
> 4. Change title and submit update.
>
> **Note:** After submit it will take time to update your info in Playstore (in 24 hours)