# How to rename google play console suspended app

Tags: android, apk, google-play-console, google-developers-console

I just made a mistake by uploading a covid tracker app called "Monitor COVID-19", I didn't know that we are not allowed to use the name COVID, so my app was suspended. I intend to change the name of my app, but I can't find a way to change it, if anyone knows please help me, thanks.
[Screen Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6YAr.png)

Comment: Probably this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63361864/4585226

Comment: I can't,  all the buttons are muted

Comment: The screen capture says: "We've sent more information to the account owner's email address."  I think you can read there what you have to do!

Comment: the email only told me how to fix it if I did have government permission (which I didn't have), so I couldn't prove it but I wanted to change the name of the app (which was the problem)

Comment: Then I guess you could delete the app from the Play Console and try to create a new one.